# Usando dois statment ao mesmo tempo sem dar "Fatal error: bind_param"

Tags: php, mysql

Na minha página de registros quero verificar os nomes de usuários e emails separadamente mas ao mesmo tempo.

Eu poderia deixar a messagem assim: `Username or email already exists` para facilitar mas eu nunca vi uma página de registro que funcionasse dessa forma.

Detalhes adicionais:

- Eu estou usando os códigos corretamente, pra cada um dos `else` tem um `if` no código.
- No banco de dados existe a tabela `users` e dentro da tabela tem `username` e `email`
- Os `stmt` estão funcionando separadamente.

  ```
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $id = '';

  else{

  $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?');
  $stmt -> bind_param("s", $username);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> bind_result($id);
  $stmt -> fetch();

      if($id > 0){
          $user_error = 'Username already exists';
      }

  }

  else{

  $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?');
  $stmt -> bind_param("s", $email);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> bind_result($id);
  $stmt -> fetch();

      if($id > 0){
          $email_error = 'Email already exists';
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: pq as duas consultas, uma só com um `or` não resolveria?

Comment: por questão de praticidade para o usuário saber se o email ou o nome de usuário já estão em uso ou ambos(que no caso do `bind_param` da Fatal error). No `mysqli -> query` isso podia ser feito facilmente. Se não for possivel eu vou ter que usar `mysqli -> query` denovo para verificar e `bind_param` para inserir os dados no banco de dados.

Answer (score 3):

A mensagem de erro do PHP engana um pouco. Você precisa "fechar" o primeiro statement, chamando o método [`close`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) após o fetch. No caso, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```php
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close(); // Liberando recursos
if ($id > 0) {
    $user_error = 'Username already exists';
}
```

Isso acontece porque o `fetch` não consumiu todo o "buffer" da query - ou seja, o seu primeiro prepared statement ainda está alocado e consumindo recursos (você só pode ter uma query "aberta" por conexão por vez). O `close` libera esses recursos e garante que você pode executar outra query nessa conexão.